# NLog: color specific words in ColoredConsole

Tags: c#, nlog

Is there a way to color specific words with NLog? My target is a `ColoredConsole`.

Let's say I want to color *longdate* red and *callsite* blue. What is the best way to do that? This doesn't seem to work:

```xml
<target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
        name="debugConsole"            
        layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${message}">
  <highlight-word text="${longdate}" foregroundColor="Red" />
  <highlight-word text="${callsite}" foregroundColor="Blue" />
</target>
```

Comment: See [the documentation for the `ColoredConsoleTarget`](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/ColoredConsole-target)

Comment: Hi Amy, thanks for your help. I've updated my question with my current attempt.

Comment: The `text` property isn't a `Layout`. That would be too expensive, therefor this wont work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrap the `longdate` and `callsite` with some chars, you could use a regex.

e.g.

```xml
<target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
        name="debugConsole"            
        layout="(${longdate}) [${callsite}] ${message}">
  <highlight-word regex="\([^)]+\)" foregroundColor="Red" />
  <highlight-word regex="\[[^]]+\]" foregroundColor="Blue" />
</target>
```

Comment: Okay, this is a potential workaround. Still curious why the above doesn't work though.

Comment: I guess ${longdate} and ${callsite} are interpreted literally.

Comment: Did a little test. Tried to log "Hello ${callsite}" and it didn't turn out colored so perhaps it isn't interpreted literally.

Comment: What's your c# call?

Comment: @Aetherix Cause `${longdate}` is considered as a Parameter placeholder by `NLog` just what `string.Format(format,params object[] args)` does

Comment: FYI, all valid "placeholders" (aka layout renderers) are listed here: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers. Those will only work for properties that are of type `Layout`